# Gradle copy task, inside filter - gradle.properties file value not working

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Inside gradle copy filter task in my `build.gradle` file, I am trying to read label value from `gradle.properties` file or from a variable. Please refer below piece of code:

```
def label = "2.2"

task filterJS(type: Copy) {
   from 'src/main/webapp'
   into 'build/webapp'

   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [vlabel: $label])   
}
```

In HTML file, I have `@vlabel@`

On running gradle `filterJS`, getting below exception

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CargoSystemUX'.

  > Could not find property `$label` on task `:CargoSystemUX:filterJS`.

I am not able to replace `$label` with its value at run time. Please suggest me the solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

def label = "2.2"

task filterJS(type: Copy) {
  from 'webapp'
  into 'filtered'
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [vlabel: label])
}
```

Without `$` when referring to `label` and also note the import statement.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is working. Also i tried  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [vlabel: "${versionLabel}".toString()]) which worked as well.